# UDF function returns dictionary, but return schema is StructType

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a following test snippet.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *


conf = SparkConf()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SQLContext(sc)

schema = StructType([
    StructField("foo", FloatType(), False),
    StructField("bar", FloatType(), False)
])

def udf_test(n):
    return {
        'foo': n / 2, 
        'bar': n * 2,
    }

test_udf = udf(udf_test, schema)
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2.0), (2, 3.0)], ["x", "y"])

base_columns = df.columns

df.withColumn('foobar', test_udf("y")).select(*base_columns, 'foobar.*').show()
```

As I understand, my UDF should return only list of values. 
But I tried to return dictionary, and it worked. Does it work correct?

I doubt that it gets dictionary, turns its values into list and than unpack them. But when you get values of dict, it can return in different order so this script can work incorrect.
Am I right?

Comment: Why do you say that your `udf` should only return a list of values? The dictionary you supplied meets the schema you specified. This code should be fine. Is it not working for you?

Comment: yes, it is working. But all code snippets I met on stackoverflow, returns list of values with specified `StructType` schema

Comment: I think test_udf is returning a named list -- not a dict.Try these 3 statements (and variations):

    `df2 = df.withColumn('foobar', test_udf("y"))
    df2.show()
    df2.select('foobar.foo').show()`